# Renderer doesn't receive data from another renderer while using ipc

Tags: electron, ipc

I am having trouble sending data from one renderer to another using ipc.  What I am trying to achieve is as following: Send a variable from index.js to cves.js. I kept console.log outputs for debugging. I get 2 messages - "index.js sends update-target-os msg." and "main.js receives update-target-os msg and sends targetOS.". But I don't get "cves.js receives targetOS".[screen capture for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LbKVB.png)

My code files are here: https://github.com/ohmtrivedi/electronProject.

Hope some one can help me with this. Just learnt electron and trying to build an app for learning purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a look at your code & to me, the issue seems to be [here](https://github.com/ohmtrivedi/electronProject/blob/master/main.js#L79), where you're sending the `targetOS` channel through `mainWindow`'s `webContents`.

`mainWindow` is the `BrowserWindow` object for the file `src/index.html`; but you want to receive it on the `BrowserWindow` object for `src/cves.html`.

One way to get to what you're trying to accomplish would be to update your code to create the `BrowserWindow` object (say, `cvesWindow`) for `src/cves.html` on `main.js` (when the `update-target-os` channel is received) instead of creating it in the `cell_cves.addEventListener` method in `index.js`.

And in `main.js`, in your `update-target-os` section, set the value you've received to a `main.js` variable, say `osGuess`.

Then, in your `cves.js` file, you could have something like:

```
 ipcRenderer.send('cves-loaded', true);
```

You could execute it once the DOM Content has been loaded. This will notify the main process that your CVES `BrowserWindow` has loaded. Then, `main.js` can then send the value on an event like:

```
ipcMain.on('cves-loaded', (event, arg) => {
  cvesWindow.webContents.send('targetOS', osGuess);
})
```

Such that it's received by the cves `BrowserWindow`.

I was able to get the value to display on the `osname` element on `cves.html` with the logic updates above.

There are possibly more ways of accomplishing this, but I would recommend going with a [Single Page Application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application) approach if all you're needing is to open a dialog that lists out additional information.

Comment: Hi Neil, I tried to make changes as per your suggestions. However, I still face the same issue, main.js receives data from index.js, but cves.js doesn't receive it when main.js sends it using BrowserWindow for cves.html. Maybe I made mistake in implementing the changes correctly. Modified code available at:  https://github.com/ohmtrivedi/electronProject. Also, if you can share your working code, it will be a big help, I am a newbie with Electron.

Comment: Sure, made a [pull request](https://github.com/ohmtrivedi/electronProject/pull/1), you can approve it to get the updated code into your repository. Looks like you're using `did-finish-load` to trigger the event. The [doc.](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/web-contents.md#instance-events) suggests that it works when the navigation is done; I've updated it to send the event when the DOM has been loaded. Hope that helps. Make a comment on the pull request if you have questions.